# glassfish-5.0 rejects connection after enabling secure admin

Tags: glassfish, netbeans-8

This is what im trying to do:
I have an glassfish installation on my raspberry pi 3 which i want to use as a remote domain with netbeans.
I know that i need the DAS for this.
When i try to enter the admin console over the webbrowser via xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:4848 and enter my credentials in the console im getting this error:
[admin console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6DiJ.png)
Now i have read that i need to enable the secure admin in order to access the console with a remote host with the following commands:

```
start-domain
enable-secure-admin
<< enter username and password >>
stop-domain
start-domain
```

After that i cant reach the admin console anymore and im getting the following error:
[error after changing secure admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JI0o.png)

EDIT:
In the server.log im getting this error:

```
[2017-03-09T00:18:13.870+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain] [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1489015093870] [levelValue: 900] [[
  GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.BackChannelFilter.handleWrite(BackChannelFilter.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$8.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.write(DefaultFilterChain.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ConnectionOutputSink.writeDownStream(Http2ConnectionOutputSink.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ConnectionOutputSink.writeDataDownStream(Http2ConnectionOutputSink.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.DefaultOutputSink.flushToConnectionOutputSink(DefaultOutputSink.java:609)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.DefaultOutputSink.writeEmptyFin(DefaultOutputSink.java:675)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.DefaultOutputSink.close(DefaultOutputSink.java:627)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2Stream.onProcessingComplete(Http2Stream.java:466)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2ServerFilter.handleEvent(Http2ServerFilter.java:569)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$6.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.notifyDownstream(FilterChainContext.java:952)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.notifyDownstream(FilterChainContext.java:934)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.OutputBuffer.endRequest(OutputBuffer.java:397)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.Response.finish(Response.java:516)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.afterService(HttpServerFilter.java:384)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext$1.run(FilterChainContext.java:202)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.resume(FilterChainContext.java:226)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler$1.run(HttpHandler.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
]]
```

Answer (score 2):

So after a few more hours of trying around, i managed to find the solution for my problem.
The newest version of glassfish (v 5.0 nightly) is bugged. An older version of glassfish (v 4.1.2) is working perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't know what is really happening with Glassfish 5, i tried to set up a domain in the development server without any specific network security and i had the same issue than you, but I set up the same version remotely in a production server with several layers of security (government network) and it works fine. I had to use the version 4.1.2 for development server )=